# redis instance restore using dump.rdb is not working

Tags: remote, redis, restore, host

I have redis instance with 10 keys in qa env. 
the instance is configured to use `dump.rdb` in `/tmp` directory . 
I ran "save" command and saw new `dump.rdb` file that was created . 
then I created new instance on other host . 
copied the `dump.rdb` to the new instance in "dir" directory as it is configured in `redis.conf` file.
I stopped the new instance and then started it. 
if I run "keys *" command on the new instance I get null . 
probably the `dump.rdb` file was not read when the server was started . 
I followed the post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497234/how-to-recover-redis-data-from-snapshotrdb-file-copied-from-another-machine

but didn't succeed.

the steps on the the old instance :

```
set aaa 111 
set bbb 222 
etc etc 
SAVE 
scp dump.rdb new_host:/dir
```

on the new host :

```
stop redis serivce 
start redis service .
redis-cli -h ... -p ... 
keys *
```

(empty list or set)

and ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

found what the problem was .

need to start the new server with a specific dump file as a parameter when starting the service though the "dir" parameter is set in the config file , it's written that when you start the service redis looks for rdb file which is configured, it didn't work for me.
had to run redis-server /path_to_config_file --dbfilename dump.rdb --dir /path_to_directory_where_the_dump_file_is_located

the command above did the job .